# angularjs filter search on objects with different hashcode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Okay the title became abit long but let me start out by an explanation:

I have a service called:

```
divisionService
```

From this i have a function that returns a list of all `Divisions` in my system.

I am using this list to populate a `select`:

```
   <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="search.division.name"
                            ng-options="item as item.name for item in auoCtrl.divisionList">
                        <option value="">Alle</option>
   </select>
```

Then i have a HTTP request that selects my users (plus some extra statistics)

```
    $http.get(api.getUrl('getUserStats', null))
    .success(function (response) {
        auoc.users = response;
    });
```

The response might look something like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Where each object looks like this:

```
object = {
avg_score : 5
completed_modules:
user: object{
          division: object{id: 19, location_id: 5, name: "Udvikling", organization_id: 1
            },
division_id: 19
id: 1
image_path: "img/profileIcon.png"
     }
}
```

I hope you can read the above there are seriously alot of data inside that user object.

Now i wish to bind my `select` to be sort my list of users by their `division` object. So i thought it would be `ng-model="search.division"` and then on my repeat do :

```
 ng-repeat="user in auoCtrl.users | filter: search"
```

Sadly when changing the value of the `select` everything got hidden

So i guess my question is. how do i search for the division in this example? :s

Comment: you can try search.division.$ on ng-model

Comment: @YOu Sadly this did not work :S

Comment: your division is an object, which field of that object you want to filter?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ekmWcd39ePJ1HmmW0zG4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, and my understanding of the question,  I have created a simple [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQOr5Zr5hbZ0LeuUA0nv?p=preview) that filters on the division name.

The complexity comes with the nested nature of the user and it's division. This mean that when applying the filter one need to 'iteratively' go through the available properties to filter on the desired one.

In this case, I have filtered users, based on the selected department name.

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in auoCtrl.users | 
              filter: {user: {division:{name:auoCtrl.selectedDivision.name}}}">
      {{user.user.division.name}}
      <br />{{user | json}}</li>
  </ul>
```